# How to fix problem with for loop (table scraping)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code below. I try to scrape a table consisting of multiple rows and 2 td's (columns) per row. When I run the below code, I only get the last row... Am I doing something wrong? I want to get all the rows (6 in total). 
Please note that `td1_7` is a list and when I run `print(td1_7[0])` for example it gives me the first row until `td1_7[6]` so that part works. I do not understand why I get only the last row when I run the code below. Could somebody please help me? Thanks.

```
columns = ['Score','Player']

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for rows in td1_7:
    score = [data.get_text(strip=True) for data in rows.find_all('td')]

temp_df = pd.DataFrame(score).transpose()
temp_df.columns = columns

final_df = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)

print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You are running a for loop and every time score gets updated with the most recent information which is the last row. Make Changes in the code such that score is initialized and then you append into that.

```
     columns = ['Score','Player']

     final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
     score = []
     for rows in td1_7: 
         score.append([data.get_text(strip=True) for data in rows.find_all('td')])

     temp_df = pd.DataFrame(score).transpose() 
     temp_df.columns = columns

     final_df = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)

     print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are doing. But you always call

```
score = [data.get_text(strip=True) for data in rows.find_all('td')]
```

in the for loop. So `score` will be the value you get from the last iteration in the for loop because you always overwrite it with the newest value. If you want to have all `scores` you could do something like:

```
scores = []
for row in td1_7:
    score = [data.get_text(strip=True) for data in rows.find_all('td')]
    scores.append(score)
print(scores) # scores is a list of lists now
```

But as I do not exactly know what input you have and what output you want this is just a guess.